# Partial update in Web API is not working

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api

I created a post method in my Web API to do a partial update of one table - to change Order Status field in the table. here is what I got so far:

```
 public IHttpActionResult UpdateOrderStatus(Order ord)
 {
     try
     {
         if (!ModelState.IsValid)
         {
             throw new ProcessException("One or more values are invalid, please check.");
         }
         using (MyContext ctx = new MyContext())
         {
             ord.StatusID = 3;
             ctx.SaveChanges();

             return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = ord.OrderID }, ord);
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         throw new ProcessException(ex.Message);

     }
}
```

I am stepping through the code and everything seems to be working - no errors, but the database is not getting updated. What am I doing wrong?

Update:

Set the StatusID in the object BEFORE passing it to the Web API method:

> var ord = { "OrderID": 1, "OrderDate": CurrentDate, "StatusID": 3};

```
public IHttpActionResult UpdateOrderStatus(Order ord)
{
   try
   {
       if (!ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           throw new ProcessException("One or more values are invalid, please check.");
       }
       using (MyContext ctx = new MyContext())
       {
           ctx.Entry(ord).State = EntityState.Modified;
           ctx.SaveChanges();

         return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = ord.OrderID }, ord);
       }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       throw new ProcessException(ex.Message);

   }
}
```

Comment: Two things: `Order.StatusID = 3;` probably should be `ord.StatusID = 3`, and you likely need this after: `ctx.Entry(ord).State = EntityState.Modified;`

Comment: Is this using Entity Framework? I suspect the problem is with how you're calling your ORM. Please tag with your ORM, or include the code for MyContext if it's handcrafted. What happens if you call the method directly?

Comment: If you're using EntityFramework then you need to inform the context about the Order object you are updating.  in EF6 you would typically have a `DbSet` property on the context called `Orders`, so I'd advise adding `ctx.Orders.Attach(Order)` before you set the `StatusID`.

Comment: Thanks guys! adding `ctx.Orders.Attach(Order)` worked! @Rob, could you please post your comment as an answer so I could accept it?

Comment: @ElenaDBA thanks - I've copied my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using EntityFramework then you need to inform the context about the Order object you are updating. In EF6 you would typically have a `DbSet` property on the context called `Orders`, so I'd advise adding `ctx.Orders.Attach(Order)` before you set the `StatusID`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:
Get orderEntity from database by comparing with ord.OrderID, Then update StatusID of that record.

```
using (MyContext ctx = new MyContext())
       {
           var orderEntity = ctx.Order.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.OrderID == ord.OrderID);
            orderEntity.StatusID = 3;
             ctx.SaveChanges();

         return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = ord.OrderID }, ord);
       }
```